# Django - gettext_lazy not working in string interpolation/concatenation (inside list)

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

I have a dictionary of items with multiple properties.

```
from django.utils.translation import (
    gettext_lazy as _,
)

{"item1": {
          "labels": [
                      _("label1"), 
                      "this is" + _("translatethis") + " label2", 
                    ]
```

These items are then serialized in **DRF**.

The problem is that

`_("label1")` is being translated

but

`"this is" + _("translatethis") + " label2"` is not translated

I tried also string interpolation, `fstring` and `.format` but nothing worked. When serializer fetches `labels`, `_("translatethis")` is not a proxy object.

Is the only way to make this work surrounding whole strings in the `gettext_lazy` ?

Comment: The main problem is that it forces to use `_('translatethis')` as string, and thus the output is a string, no longer something that is translated when needed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, yes, I understand. So I guess the only simple way to make it work is to surround whole strings with `getttext_lazy`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `_('translatethis')` is not a string, but something that promises, when necessary, to be a string. When you however concatenate it with a string, it is time to keep its promise, and it thus presents a string, and it no longer can thus, when needed, check the active language.

An option might be to work with a lazy object, like:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy


def text_join(*items):
    return ''.join(items)


text_join_lazy = lazy(text_join, str)

{
    'item1': {
        'labels': [
            _('label1'),
            text_join_lazy('this is ', _("translatethis"), ' label2'),
        ]
    }
}
```